# Не задаются cookie в laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Не работают куки в laravel 5.2, не понимаю, что я делаю не так:

```
Route::get('set', function () {
    Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever('cart_id', 123));
});

Route::get('get', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    dump($request->cookie('cart_id'));

});
```

сначала захожу на /set, затем на /get, но отображается `null`. В чем может быть проблема?

UPD: дамп $request:

```
Request {#40 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure {#114 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure {#113 ▶}
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#42 ▶}
  +request: ParameterBag {#48 ▶}
  +query: ParameterBag {#48 ▶}
  +server: ServerBag {#45 ▶}
  +files: FileBag {#44 ▶}
  +cookies: ParameterBag {#43 ▼
    #parameters: array:3 [▼
      "cart_id" => null
      "XSRF-TOKEN" => null
      "laravel_session" => null
    ]
  }
  +headers: HeaderBag {#46 ▼
    #headers: array:9 [▼
      "host" => array:1 [▶]
      "connection" => array:1 [▶]
      "cache-control" => array:1 [▶]
      "user-agent" => array:1 [▶]
      "upgrade-insecure-requests" => array:1 [▶]
      "accept" => array:1 [▶]
      "accept-encoding" => array:1 [▶]
      "accept-language" => array:1 [▶]
      "cookie" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "cart_id=eyJpdiI6IldNbjJwMHdRclBmWkFkUFJ3SnJ6Z2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVnhBWGl3ODFBaGhwTCtSc0NoSmlLUT09IiwibWFjIjoiYjU2NjRmNDI4OGQ4NGZmZjNjMDhmYTEwMWJlOWQ2ZjUwYjAxNTMxYjU2OWY3Y2I0NjYxNzQzZTNhZjVkMDcxOSJ9; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ino2ckNVSU5cL3VEcE5VQWRqQm1wTkV3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkF2b1Y0VDFkMlVqam8zeWVJQk55Mm96XC9PZFlyZUxma3FBTXNBV2VoK3AyTkp5Q2RNOHZtQnRyMFB0a3c0Mm5cL1hJdkkyY1haUHhZV0FEejdKSjMzaHc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjFlNjVkZDE2NDJiYjA2MDQzM2JiYWYzMWY2YWRiNTk0ZDM4MjBlNmEzZmEwNTUxZWUzY2NmYmEyZDljMmYwOGIifQ%3D%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Imh1QW1iamlscnVpV3JFTThHYWdTNkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZElUMU1MZlRwa1BRZFd6T0pWMGhSanNCcmVNcjdEUGJrd2Zhc3RqbFUzVFBOamxsclBnbWhHcVk4QXFXU2VFMkVGYXBUSm4xVVFvcGZoZnVxN1VTVnc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjkyYjA5YTI3MmE3MWE5OWRhNDBjYWZkZjQwZjk0NjI1OTY4MGNjZDM4ZDQ4YWE3YjdkMWMxNmQwZjgxMzQzZTYifQ%3D%3D"
      ]
    ]
    #cacheControl: array:1 [▶]
  }
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/get"
  #requestUri: "/get"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "GET"
  #format: null
  #session: Store {#153 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
}
```

Comment: используете middleware group "web" в роутерах?

Comment: @EvgeniyDomatskiy да, конечно